# How to pass a JavaScript function to another process over JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, function-pointers

I'm doing a chrome extension -- how would I pass a function from background to a content-script instance, obviously the function needs to be serialized?

Is it just okay to do eval(function_string)?

This is my first time practicing such voodoo, help invited.

Comment: As long as you can trust that the `function_string` will be a function or some other trusted code, and not some XSS attack or something

Comment: Or if you passed the right stuff and set it up, you could use the `Function` constructor - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: I trust it. The background distributes 'scripting language' script to content-scripts which then execute it. The scripts are written per application, but the execution model of bg-content-script is the same.

Comment: Stop. Before practicing vodoo, please tell us [what you actually want to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Serializing functions (and loosing all their context through this) is seldom a good solution.

Comment: Okay perhaps it is better to say "serialize a script" (which hopefully will contain the context of all the functions defined in it), there is no data in scope to close over (except for the function definitions in the script). I just want to define these functions in one javascript VM, and send them (via chrome.tabs message passing) to another javascript VM where they can be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used to achieve this :

The custom scripting language script containing functions to be sent :

```
// An example script
// Showing how dependent functions are defined later on
// With functions that have no dependencies grouped together in an associative array
// preceding, in the execution_context_loader's list, the functions that depend on them.

var collection_script.execution_context_loader = [
 {
      fa:function(a) { return a+1; },
      fb:function(b) { return b*2; },
      fc:function(c) { return c-3; }
 },
 {
      fabc:function(a,b,c) {
          return  window.qwontical.execution_context.fa(a)^
                   window.qwontical.execution_context.fb(b)^
                    window.qwontical.execution_context.fc(c);

      }
 }

];

var script_point = {
    name : 'alpha',
    source : '/root/space',
    data_args : [ '/j1', '/j2', '/j3' ],
    function_applied : 'fabc'
};
```

Which when executed on the other side (say by calling some function `execute("alpha");`) will apply the function fabc (serialized and revivified) to the resources found at `/root/space/j1`, and also `.../j2` and `.../j3`.

On the function sending side :

```
// Function to package a script's execution context for dispatch to a collection script

function package_script_for_dispatch( collection_script ) {
            console.log(collection_script);
            if ( !!collection_script.execution_context_loader ) {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < collection_script.execution_context_loader.length; i += 1) {
                            for ( var func_def in collection_script.execution_context_loader[i] ) {
                                    collection_script.execution_context_loader[i][func_def] = collection_script.execution_context_loader[i][func_def].toString();
                                    console.log("Packed : " + collection_script.execution_context_loader[i][func_def]);
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    collection_script.execution_context_loader = {};
            }
    }
```

On the function receiving side :

```
 for( var i = 0; i < collectionscript.execution_context_loader.length; i+= 1) {
            for (var func_name in collectionscript.execution_context_loader[i] ) {
                    var func_def_string = collectionscript.execution_context_loader[i][func_name];
                    console.log("About to revivify " + func_name + " : " + func_def_string);
                    eval("window.qwontical.execution_context['"+func_name+"'] = "+func_def_string);
            }
    }
```

The calling convention for such a function is then

`window.qwontical.execution_context[func_name](args...);`

This enables functions to be defined in a script by their name and then used later on, after that script has been serialized and "revivified"